# En quoi « cultivé en intérieur » diffère de « ...à l'intérieur » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, locutions, formulation

Comment explique-t-on la différence entre *cultivé en intérieur* et *cultivé à l'intérieur* (botanique) ? La première est-elle une simple lexicalisation de la deuxième avec un sens identique, y a-t-il une différence de sens entre la formulation avec *[en](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/0)* et *[à](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0/0) [l'](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%27/0)* ici ? La lexicalisation c'est *en intérieur* ou ça englobe aussi le verbe ; il semble que le verbe *cultiver* s'emploie [habituellement](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/rdp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=97T009neRBig.html#zz97T009neRBig) avec les prépositions *dans, par, sous et sur*, est-ce que ça ajoute ou confirme quelque chose dans l'analyse ? La préposition *en* est employée comment ou pour introduire quel genre de complément et s'agit-il simplement d'un complément circonstanciel de lieu ou d'autre chose ?

Answer (score 5):

Je dirais que "en intérieur" répond à la question "comment ?" plutôt qu'à la question "où ?".

```
- Où vas tu ?
- À l'intérieur. 

- Comment sont cultivés ces légumes ?
- En intérieur
```

Comment: On dira plutôt *sous serre* dans la majorité des cas.

Answer (score 1):

En effet, "en intérieur" s'oppose simplement à "à l'extérieur", alors que "à l'intérieur" semble plus defini, et quand on entend "cultivé à l'intérieur" cela donne  l'impression que la phrase n'est pas terminée (à l'intérieur de quoi ?).

Comment: "en intérieur" s'oppose à "en extérieur" qui existe aussi, bien qu'on lui préfère je pense souvent "en plein air".